# Get "latest" gauge value for workers

Tags: prometheus

We have two workers consuming events from a queue and doing some processing. Both workers update the same gauge, call it `x`, during a run. The workers never run in parallel. The workers expose metrics via http that gets scraped.

What we want is to display the "latest" value for the gauge x regardless of worker.

We use `changes` currently but this prevents us from showing gauge values after a fresh deploy since the gauges get reset.

```
                                ┌────────┐
                                │        │
      Worker 1  ────────────────┘        │
      x gauge                            └─────────────



                ─┐                               ┌────────
      Worker 2   │                               │
      x gauge    └───────────────────────────────┘



                ─┐              ┌────────┐
      Want       │              │        │       ┌─────────
      x gauge    └──────────────┘        │       │
                                         └───────┘

                 │              │        │       │
Time   ──────────┴──────────────┴────────┴───────┴────────────►
             Worker 2       Worker 1   Worker 1  Worker 2
             updates x      updates x  updates x updates x
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is not possible. For Prometheus these are 2 different Timelines and there is no way to find out which is the "correct" one.

I guess you need to store the value of the gauge in a common data store (db, redis,...) and then provide the gauge from all of the workers (all with the same value and then you don't have to care which timeline you show (simply show the first one).